# Windows server - what edition for active directory logging only

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2022

for my organization (40-50 users) I need a Domain Controller. The server will be used only to log users on their PC/Notebook (with windows pro edition) and to set policy on the PC (like to block pc usb ports or other policies).

Can I buy a windows server 2022 essential edition or I need a Standard edition with 40-50 user CAL? The users must not access to the server with rdp or other services.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Essentials edition is limited to 25 users. So it does fit your requirements.
Consider using Standard Edition, or look into a cloud model with Azure AD and Intune. With cloud model you would not need to have on-premises server hardware at all

Comment: Hi j-M and thank you for the reply. With standard edition I need 40 user-cal (or device-cal), am I right?

Comment: And not having local hardware at all but being cloud base is disputable - but the dispute goes HEAVILY into a "yes" if those are laptops that are used outside the office regularly.

Comment: @MenInTheMiddle yes you do. But it is always a good idea to consult with a reseller who would sell you licenses/hardware. OEM license are much cheaper. But please consider going cloud first, as it bring benefit you would miss with on-premises setup. E.g. hybrid ways of working from anywhere are much easier to implement with cloud-based setup